# Free body diagram

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

I recently learned how to draw free body diagrams. Suppose a block is kept on ground and we need to draw FBD of ground. One force would be reaction force by block on ground. Will we also include the gravitational force on ground by block $(= mg )$  as a reaction force to gravitational pull on box by earth?[image: This is what my teachers say is FBD of surface]

Comment: If you have received the answer for many of your Q on physics. Then , do accept them and don’t leave them open. Other users may think that you have still not understood the answer even though you have answers.

Comment: ok sir I understood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, when considering the forces acting on the ground, in theory you should include both

- the downwards normal force by the block and
- the upwards gravitational force by the block.

In fact the gravitational force felt by the earth due to the object is exactly equal to the gravitational force felt by the object due to earth, just opposite. This Is newton's m 3rd law. The influence in the object is just much greater (it reaches higher acceleration during a fall e.g.) due to its much smaller mass.

Comment: but sir all of my teachers say that mg is acting on center of earth and therefore we should not include it in our free body diagram of surface of earth

Comment: they say surface is different thing and whole body is different thing

Comment: what I think is same as you said that even if surface is different thing it is a part of whole body only

Comment: @lalittolani If your teachers say so, then ask them if it isn't true that there's a gravitational force in the Earth by *the moon*. We know this is true simply due to tidal action in the oceans. Next, ask them how big this gravitational pull is. They will most likely use Newton's law of gravitation, $$F_g=G\frac{mM}{r^2},$$ to calculate it. Then ask them what the gravitational pull *in the moon due to Earth* is. They will use the same formula and as you can see, the result will be *the same*! Those two forces are exactly the same. This is a consequense of Newton's 3rd law.

Comment: @lalittolani Now ask them why the moon is different from a human-scale object like the block in your scenario. Gravity is exerted between *any* two bodies with mass - the rock has mass. So it pulls in Earth with a gravitational force just like Earth pulls in it with a gravitational force. And via the same argument as above, those two forces *are equal*. Sure, the influence is much greater on the rock due to its smaller mass (this is Newton's 2nd law), and the influence by this force in Earth is basically negligible. Nevertheless both feel the same gravitational force.

Comment: @lalittolani  Often for such smaller objects that don't extend far in altitude (so that distance differences from point to point are negligible; more technically, so that the centre-of-gravity coincides with the centre-of-mass), we encompass some of the parameters from Newton's law of gravitation into a constant that we call the **gravitational acceleration** $g$, $$g=G\frac{M}{r^2}.$$ Then the formula becomes the well-known: $$F_g=mg.$$

Comment: @lalittolani Perhaps you could upload a picture of the free-body diagram of the ground that your teachers prefer. You cannot have a free-body diagram of the "surface" of anything; "free" means that an isolated object is shown, such as a chunk of Earth (with reaction forces where it meets the rest of the Earth) or the entire Earth.

Comment: @Steeven sir my teacher don't doubt newtons third law, what they say is that if we have to draw a free body diagram of ground surface then we will not include gravitational pull on ground by block since this pull acts at the center of earth

Comment: @Chemomechanics yes sure

Comment: @lalittolani This doesn't make much sense, since if you only consider a small portion of the Earth - such as just the surface, by which I guess you mean a portion of soil or so - then even this small portion of Earth feels a gravitational pull by the rock. It *also* feels a gravitational pull by the rest of Earth, which is why it doesn't start accelerating upwards towards the rock.

Comment: @lalittolani Note, though, that gravity does not only act from the centre of Earth. It acts from every single particle with mass. But, from the outside, the *effect* of Earth's total gravitational force is the same as if Earth was just a point-mass - of this reason we very often average down Earth's gravity or mass into it's centre, since that simplifies a lot of things. But as soon as you start chopping off pieces of Earth and considering them separately, then we should be careful since they naturally carry mass as well and thus experience and exert gravitational forces as well.

Comment: therefore @Chemomechanics is correct by saying that it is not sensible to draw FBD of a surface

Comment: i uploaded a pic of what my teachers say about FBD of surface

Comment: @lalittolani Yes, I agree with Chemomechanics in his comment above. But be aware that possibly you and your teacher have misunderstood each other. If we set up the free-body diagram of **the ground**, then what I have described here applies. If we set up the free-body diagram of **the rock**, then your teacher is not wrong in saying that only the normal force acts from the surface (and the gravity (or weight) acts from the rock's centre). Be sure that you are talking about the same object that you want to draw the FBD for.

Comment: @Steeven my teacher was talking about ground surface only and accordingly as you said that what you described will apply , in case we are taking of stone then we will only consider reaction force by block, reaction force by surface below the stone and it's weight only in it's FBD

Comment: @lalittolani I'd recommend you to discuss this with the teacher to have it cleared out.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a block on ground. Then , it’s free body diagram is as follows and as you wrote in your question , you are right!.

[image]

mg,N1 and N2 are just action reaction pairs of each other according to the Newton’s third law.

N1=N2.

I hope your question is now clear.

Answer (score -1):

When a block is put on the ground. The gravitaional force of earth attracts the block with force $mg$ (More precisely, the centre of earth attracts the block and vice-versa). As a result the ground gets pushed and the ground exerts normal reaction on the block ($N$).
So in $y$ direction there are 2 forces on block -
i) Gravitational force by the earth ($mg$) in $-y$ direction.
ii) Normal reaction by ground ($N$) in $+y$ direction
As there is no vertical motion of block, so $N=mg$